# Как установить файл из архива tar.bz2

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Хочу установить программу. С официального сайта скачал архив `tar.bz2`.

```
tar jxvf file.tar.bz2
```

Таким способом распаковать получается и после создается папка с файлами. Там программа открывается и даже могу пользоваться, но в Главном меню ее нету.

Как мне правильно распаковать и установить программу на Ubuntu?

Comment: А deb-пакетов вообще нету?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужно создать файл в `~/.local/share/applications` для текущего пользователя или в `/usr/share/applications` для всех пользователей (во втором случае нужны права root), с любым именем и расширением `.desktop`.

Файл должен начинаться строкой `[Desktop Entry]`; все строки, начинающиеся с `#`, считаются комментариями.

Затем нужно заполнить его следующей информацией в формате `ключ=значение`:

### Обязательные поля

**Type** – тип лаунчера: Application, Link или Directory (в вашем случае Application).

**Name** – отображаемое имя.

**Exec** – команда запуска.

### Дополнительные поля

**Version** – версия.

**Encoding** – кодировка.

**GenericName** – общее имя.

**NoDisplay** – булево (true/false). Если true, то запись не будет отображаться в меню.

**Hidden** – булево (true/false). Если true, то помечает запись как удалённую и не просто скрывает из меню, а полностью игнорирует её существование.

**Comment** – комментарий, который будет выводиться в меню и всплывающих подсказках.

**Icon** – путь к иконке.

**OnlyShowIn** – если вы используете несколько DE, то можете указать, в какой именно запись будет отображаться.

**NotShowIn** – если указать, то будет отображаться во всех DE, кроме указанной.

**Path** – путь к директории, из которой будет запускаться команда.

**Terminal** – булево (true/false). Если true, запускает команду через эмулятор терминала.

**MimeType** – здесь можно указать mime-типы, с которыми ваша запись будет по умолчанию ассоциироваться.

**Categories** – имена категорий, в которых запись будет отображаться (через точку с запятой). Корректные имена можете посмотреть [здесь](https://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/apa.html).

### Пример .desktop файла

`[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Path=$HOME/MyApp
Exec=$HOME/MyApp/MyApp.sh
Name=My Application
Icon=$HOME/Icons/MyIcon.png`

Answer (score 1):

Это точно не для ubuntu, в том смысле что это не debian пакет ( deb ). В таком случае должен быть файл *.desktop, его надо скопировать в /usr/share/applications. И он должен указывать на твою программу, в тот каталог, где программа находиться. Файл *.desktop как раз и будет виден в меню. Но бывают и с ним проблемы, у меня например torbrowser не показывает в меню, хотя файл desktop скопирован.

Comment: *.desktop не нужно ни от куда копировать. его нужно создавать самому с нуля и прописывать в нём всю необходимую информацию конкретно для своей системы, со всеми актуальными путями.

Comment: Это на тот случай если его нет. А если есть, то копировать.

Comment: если вы его просто скопировали, то не удивляйтесь что он не отображается в меню, поскольку пути в нём ссылаются на несуществующие в вашей системе файлы/директории.

Comment: Вообще то на существующие. Пути нормальные. Раньше работало нормально, но потом перестало.